Constructing a map that accurately mimics 1-point perspective
Problem
Provide the set of all possible maps $\Phi(x,y)$ such that the image of the usual square coordinate grid under $\Phi$ is a 1-point perspective grid with vanishing point at $(p,q)$.
Note that such a map can be used to demonstrate the projective equivalence of all conics.

Solution
Here is what I believe to be a set of conditions which, when satisfied, are necessary and sufficient for accurately mimicking 1-point perspective in the way we desire our map to:

the image of any vertical line is an element of a pencil of lines through $(p,q)$
the image of any vertical line has an accumulation point at $(p,q)$
the image of any horizontal line is an horizontal line
the image of any point on the line $y=q-1$ is the same as the preimage
the image of any diagonal line is a diagonal line whose slope has the same sign

Let $\Phi(x,y)=\left(f(x,y),g(x,y)\right)$
WLOG, let $(p,q)=(0,1)$ (we can perform the necessary translation later)
To satisfy conditions 1 and 4 simultaneously, we require that $g(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{x}f(x,y)$
Thus, $\Phi(x,y)=(x(1-g(x,y)),g(x,y))$
To satisfy condition 4, we also require that $\Phi(x,0)=(x(1-g(x,0)),g(x,0))=(x,0)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
Since this implies that $g(x,0)=0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can conclude that $g_x(x,y)=0$ and thus $\Phi(x,y)=(x(1-h(y)),h(y))$ for some univariate function $h$
To satisfy condition 5, we require $\Phi(x,x)$ to be such that $h(x)=ax(1-h(x))$ for some $a>0$
Thus, if $a>0$ then $h(x)$ can be any function of the form $\frac{ax}{ax+1}$.
Thus, we finally have $\Phi(x,y)=(\frac{x}{1+ay},\frac{ay}{1+ay})$
After a translation by $(p,q-1)$, we finally have our answer:
$$\Phi(x,y)=\left(p+\frac{x}{ay+1},q-1+\frac{ay}{ay+1}\right)$$ for any $a>0$
Here is a desmos simulation to verify this result
